# FTP url regular expression in C POSIX

Tags: c, regex, url, ftp, posix

I'm trying to make a simple FTP url parser with the help of POSIX regex.I'm using ERE(Extended Regular Expressions). I came up with 2 regular expressions(one for when the user types the username and the password and another for anonymous):

```
/* ftp syntax */
ftp://[<user>:<password>@]<host>/<url-path>


/* The regular expression pattern (might be changed) */
const char* pattern = "ftp://(([a-z0-9]+):([a-z0-9]+)@)*([\\.a-z0-9]+)/([\\./a-z0-9]+)$";

/* The anonymous one */
const char* patternAnon = "ftp://([\\.a-z0-9]+)/([\\./a-z0-9]+)$";
```

My main difficulty is trying to combine the two of them into one single regular expression. Thank you.

Comment: FYI: The `:<password>` and `/<url-path>` components are optional, and a `:<port>` component may also be specified immediately after the `<host>` component. Thus `ftp://user@host` and `ftp://user@host:123` are both valid FTP URLs. This may or may not be relevant depending on your specific situation, of course.

Comment: I know, that's why I use 2 of them. I check the first and if it doesn't match I check the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will match both patterns you've specified:

```
ftp://([a-z0-9]+:[a-z0-9]+@)?([\\.a-z0-9]+)/([\\./a-z0-9]+)$
```

Though, I should also mention that your patterns (and thus this one), also match many invalid url formats, and miss some valid ones.  I'll leave that to you, but at least you can see the way to make the `user:pass@` part optional in my example here.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not concerned with special cases. This one should do.